# why i m getting error undefined veriable when all works fine

Tags: php

why m i getting this error is it just a fake error should i hide it with '@' ? i m making a login/register system everything works fine only this error is shown atm.. but i can register or login change password everything

**Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\loginsistem\classes\Cookie.php on line 4**

```
class Cookie {
    public static function exists() {
        return (isset($_COOKIE[$name])) ? true : false;
    }
    public static function get($name) {
        return $_COOKIE[$name];
    }
    public static function put($name, $value, $expiry) {
        if(setcookie($name, $value, time() + $expiry, '/')) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public static function delete($name) {
        self::put($name, '', time() - 1);
    }

}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a "fake error", nor is it ever a good idea to use `@`.  In your `exists()` function, you reference `$name`, but it's not set in that function.  You probably want to add it as a parameter.

Comment: `$name` is not in scope in the first function that accesses `$_COOKIE[$name]`, `exists()`

Comment: You passed `$name` as a parameter to `get()`, and we can only assume you meant to do the same as `public static function exists($name)`

Comment: Your login system is completely insecure.

Comment: Security is **hard**.  Do not re-invent the wheel.  You should use an existing, proven authentication system.

Comment: Taking the time to use proper grammar on your question often shows effort and gets you better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your method signature like this.

```
 public static function exists($name) {
                             //^^^^^^ <--------- Pass the parameter $name
```

If you had a good PHP IDE you could have found this error whilst you were writing the code itself.